# Running simple node js application on docker returns Empty reply from server

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to run basic node js application from docker container in ubuntu VM,but curl command from ubuntu vm terminal giving below error.

$ curl http://localhost:49160
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
71df92f95049        helloworld          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:49160->8080/tcp   sharp_lumiere

Comment: Which Docker command did you use to run your application? Did you specify the flag -p?

Comment: thanks @DucNguyen  for the reply.I used sudo docker run -p 49160:8080 --name hello hello-world

Comment: Can you make sure your Node.js is listening on port 8080?

Comment: I had given 0.0.0.0:49160->8080/tcp in my first description.Any other command I need to run and show?

Comment: I know you'd given 0.0.0.0:49160->8080/tcp. But I think maybe your Node.js app doesn't listen on 8080? I can't tell.

Comment: is there a command to verify that ? Please see my dockerfile :FROM node:12.16.3
WORKDIR /code
ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
COPY package.json /code/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /code
CMD ["node", "src/server.js" ]     and I have server.listen('0.0.0.0',8080) in .js